# view 1 column value 3 times using where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

is it possible to view 1 column value 3 times using where clause..
for eg

```
select Lastname from Emplyee where firstname = 'John' , 'Mike' , 'Harry'
```

It should return values like

```
firstname      lastname
John           Moraes
Mike           Tan
Harry          Potter
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: Read more about the IN() function here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

Answer (score 4):

You can use `a in (v1, v2, v3)`. You also need `firstname` in your `select` clause to get it in your result set.

```
select Firstname, Lastname from Emplyee where firstname in ('John' , 'Mike' , 'Harry')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select Lastname from Emplyee where firstname IN('John' , 'Mike' , 'Harry')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query

```
SELECT firstname, lastname FROM Emplyee WHERE firstname IN ('John','Mike','Harry');
```